# Limit of a trigonometric function $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin{\pi x}}{1 - x^2}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, limits

I'm trying to find the following limit:

$$
\lim_ {x \to 1} \frac{\sin{\pi x}}{1 - x^2}
$$

I can't figure it out how to reach the fundamental trigonometric limit. Everything i see is that the denominator is a difference between squares, and then can be factorated

$$
\lim_ {x \to 1} \frac{\sin{\pi x}}{(1 - x)(1 + x)}
$$

I'd like to know how can i simplify this expression to eliminate the indetermination.

Comment: Hint: $\sin\theta= -\sin(  \theta-\pi)=\sin(\pi-\theta)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $y = 1-x$. Then we get that
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 1}\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{(1-x)(1+x)} & =\lim_{y \to 0}\dfrac{\sin(\pi (1-y))}{y(2-y)}\\
& =\lim_{y \to 0}\dfrac{\sin(\pi y)}{y} \dfrac1{(2-y)}\\
& =\lim_{y \to 0}\dfrac{\sin(\pi y)}{y} \cdot \lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac1{(2-y)}\\
& = \pi \cdot \dfrac12 & \left(\text{Recall that}\lim_{y \to 0}\dfrac{\sin(a y)}{y} = a \right)\\
& = \dfrac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 5):

You can also appeal to L'Hopital's Rule:

$$ \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(1-x^2)} =\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\pi \cos(\pi x)}{-2 x} \\
  = \frac{\pi}{2}$$